# Crontab entry to update my xmltv epg - xlm file - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server

Tags: 14.04, scripts, cron

I have made a small script like this:-

```
#!/bin/sh
tv_grab_uk_rt -output /var/www/xml/tv.xml
```

and called it `xml.sh`. I have saved this script at /usr/bin/xmltvscript/xml.sh

I can run this fine with `sudo ./xml.sh`

I then typed `sudo crontab -e` and made this entry:-

```
01 08 * * * /usr/bin/xmltvscript/xml.sh
```

but it does not run. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could doesn't work because `tv_grab_uk_rt` option `-output` is wrong.

Right option is `--output <file>` (use 2 dashes instead of 1).

You can look at related [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tv_grab_uk_rt.1p.html).

**Update**

If you want to run a cron script every tot minutes (e.g. 5) you can use the following command:

```
*/5 * * * * <script_file>
```

Comment: Hi, I just changed to two dashes, but - believe you me, it works with one dash (for the last two weeks running manually).

Comment: @D Forster The script works  manually?

Comment: Hi, Yes, just added the two dashes like you indicated and ran again. All good. Dan

Comment: @D Forster Sorry, I didn't understand. Now works the script or cron daemon?

Comment: My mistake.. Script, I just ran using sudo ./xml.sh. Is there a command to run the cron now (or do I change the time to run the cron every minute to test)?